# Configuration Options in Gems Used in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm working with a Ruby Gem that access a public API via a configurable URL. I want to have a default value built into the gem, but the ability to override that as a configuration or runtime option inside a Rails 3 app that uses the gem. What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can expose the configuration value as a class-level property. For example, if you were developing MyConfigurableGem, you could have

```
def self.my_database_preference=
  #set override some default. 
end
```

And if your user was working with a rails app, you could suggest there be a file app/config/configurable_gem_override.rb with the following

```
MyConfigurableGem.my_database_preference = "sqlite3"
```

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the sort of thing I was looking for.